# getting error while executing the rebuild index queries (ORA-29874 and ORA-29960)

Tags: oracle, rebuild

Code:

```
create or replace procedure REBUILD_X_TEXT
IS

 err_code NUMBER;
 err_msg  VARCHAR2(100);
 
Begin
 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX TWPROD.X_TEXT_ENTITY rebuild parameters(''REPLACE metadata sync(every "SYSDATE+15/1440")'')'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX TWPROD.X_TEXT_ENTITY NOPARALLEL'; 

exception
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
     
      err_code := SQLCODE;
      err_msg  := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 100);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Rebuild index failed : Error code ' || err_code || ': ' || err_msg);
  

END REBUILD_X_TEXT;
```

Error:

> Connecting to the database PROD
> ORA-29874: warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER routine
> ORA-29960: line 1,
> DRG-10595: ALTER INDEX X_TEXT_ENTITY failed
> DRG-50857: oracle error in drvddl.Resubmit_job
> ORA-27486: insufficient privileges
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.REBUILD_X_TEXT", line 7
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> Process exited.
> Disconnecting from the database PROD.

Comment: Remove the WHEN OTHERS and let the error propogate up the stack as oracle designed it to.  Why are you even doing this?  It is very rare that an index benefits from being rebuilt. https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/index-internals-rebuilding-the-truth/.

Comment: Connecting to the database PROD.
ORA-29874: warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER routine
ORA-29960: line 1, 
DRG-10595: ALTER INDEX X_TEXT_ENTITY failed
DRG-50857: oracle error in drvddl.Resubmit_job
ORA-27486: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.REBUILD_X_TEXT", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database PROD.

Comment: Hi Heena, what user executes the procedure REBUILD_X_TEXT ? Is it sys?

Comment: Yes I am using SYS user still it's giving an error insufficient privileges

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is about a text index (since it's name is X_TEXT_ENTITY) and the procedure is being executed as a "normal" user other than sys.

In this case please check whether user has create table privilege and, if not, issue it.
I see you know how to grant a privilege to a user, but I'll still posting the statement in case of someone will find the answer later.

```
grant create table on USERNAME;
```

The reason is for each TEXT index Oracle creates a set of tables and this is the most often reason why people see the "ORA-27486: insufficient privileges" when dealing with text indexes.

Since the problem occurs on altering index, you may need to play with "alter any table" privilege, which violates the database security. If the security aspect is a concern, you might wanted to check tables created for that index (their names start with "DR$INDEX_NAME%") and issue "alter table" grants to a user that executes REBUILD_X_TEXT

Comment: I tried doing this still error persist, also this is Domain index

Comment: @HeenaShaikh can this user execute "ALTER INDEX TWPROD.X_TEXT_ENTITY ..." statements alone without plsql?

Comment: getting error for alone statement as well
SQL Error: ORA-29874: warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER routine
ORA-29960: line 1, 
DRG-10595: ALTER INDEX X_TEXT_ENTITY failed
DRG-50857: oracle error in drvddl.Resubmit_job
ORA-27486: insufficient privileges
29874. 00000 -  "warning in the execution of ODCIINDEXALTER routine"
*Cause:    A waring was returned from the ODCIIndexAlter routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly
           Check the user defined warning log tables for greater details.

Comment: My last idea would to be recreate the index. If this doesn't help - I'm out of ideas